# pdfbox 3.0.0 library using in android studio for reading .pdf

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

I'm trying to read .pdf file for that I'm using following code in activity button click but `'Loader.loadPDF(file);'` not work every time it shows me the error.

```
public void ReadMyPdfFile(View v){

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "mPDF.pdf");

            List<String> pageTexts = new ArrayList<>();
            PDDocument pdDocument = null;
            try {
                pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(file);//<-- error on this line
                int k = 0;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ReadMyPdfFile: Exception++ " + e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

logcat

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Point; at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(PDDocument.java:104) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.createDocument(PDFParser.java:209) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:187) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:156) at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:466) at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:348) at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:303) at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:246)`

In 'build.gradle' following dependencies are added

```
implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0'    
implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:3.0.0'
```

Can any body help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the normal PDFBox on Android as it has dependencies on the Standard Java graphics library `awt` that the Java on Android does not use.

There is a port for Android, so use the following dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.27.0'
}
```

Though I found the built in pdf libraries [PDFDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) and [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) were good enough not to need external libraries like `pdfbox` or `itext` with their licensing/compatibility problems.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to read individual text from each page of `'.pdf'` file. and I don't thing so that `PDFDocument` and `PdfRenderer` has this support.

Comment: Yes true, the native pdf libraries don't offer the ability to extract data from a PDF

Comment: Now im tring this library may be this will work `'itextg'`.

Comment: Just beware of the licensing problems with `itext`, you might need to buy a commercial license.